# client side validation in htmlhelper without Model Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I visited through different links but couldn't find desired answer. I am not using model for this view. Before sending data to server I want to check whether the text input is null or not.How can I validate it?

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="container">
    <h2>Student Information</h2>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("insert", "Menu", FormMethod.Post, new { id="target"}))
    {
        <label>First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" id="f_name" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" >Insert</button>
    }
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#target".submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            //return false;
        })
    }) 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I use empty string ('') instead of null since usually empty textbox are just empty string and not necessarily null.

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('button.btn').unbind();
    $('button.btn').click(function () {

        if($("#f_name").val() == ''){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    })
})
</script>
```

Comment: sir I tried using empty string but data was sent to server. I don't actually know where the return value is catched.

Comment: I edited my code, I used period instead of # since you are using class on your button. Kindly try again. @NirojDahal

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want custom script for validating data on client side, you can use `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobstrusive.js`. This will work just like mvc validation rules(Actually this validation logic is generated by MVC itself on the view when client side validation is enabled).

Just add this three script file inside your page.

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/5.2.3/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

Or you can select from your Script folder inside MVC application.
And Try to add following attribute in your Htmlelement for validation.

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Student Information</h2>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("insert", "Menu", FormMethod.Post, new { id="target"}))
    {
        <label>First Name:</label>
        <input data-val="true" data-val-required="First Name field is required." type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" id="firstname" />

        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="firstname" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" >Insert</button>
    }
</div>
```

This will work just like MVC validation inside your view.
You can get more information how to use **JqueryValidate** and **jquery** **unobtrusive** by clicking on this link : http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html

Comment: How can I valid a known string? For example: what should I do if I don't want to post data to server if the firstname is not equal to 'Niroj'.

Comment: Then try to add this snippet in input field data-val-regex ="The User Name is not valid" data-val-regex-pattern="^Niroj$". Please look into link for more info. And upvote if this answer helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value with a simple jQuery statement - $("#f_name").val() and then check if it is null  $("#f_name").val() == null

So your complete javascript would be

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#target".submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if($("#f_name").val() == null){
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        })
    })

</script>
```

Comment: sir I just didn't have an idea how to stop data to be sent to server.Can you please write a code to stop server side processing after that?

Comment: Still data is being submitted to server. Where is the return value from JavaScript caught ? Sir could you please make me understand?

Comment: You are overriding the submit method of the form, if it returns false then the browser will not submit the form so you should not see any data being sent to the server